# Convert DataFrame to dictionary with sub-dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame

```
          name  filter      date     value
0     sum_buys     0.5  20200512  6.480628
1    sum_sells     0.5  20200512  5.019421
2     sum_buys     0.6  20200512  7.463128
3    sum_sells     0.6  20200512  5.836488
4     sum_buys     0.7  20200512  8.684414
```

I need to convert it to 2 dictionaries:

```
sum_buys[filter][date]
sum_sells[filter][date]
```

So, for example:

```
sum_buys[0.5][20200512] = 6.480628
sum_buys[0.7][20200512] = 8.684414
```

How to do it using pandas methods without iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have a handful of columns you can use `to_dict()` method on your dataframe followed by a dictionary comprehension to get the data structure you want.

Creating nested dictionaries isn't something you can vectorize, but by moving the iteration step to a smaller dictionary instead of using `iterrows()` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680032/create-nested-dict-from-pandas-dataframe) you should see some performance gains.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
          name  filter      date     value
0     sum_buys     0.5  20200512  6.480628
1    sum_sells     0.5  20200512  5.019421
2     sum_buys     0.6  20200512  7.463128
3    sum_sells     0.6  20200512  5.836488
4     sum_buys     0.7  20200512  8.684414
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

sum_buys_data = (
    df[df["name"] == "sum_buys"]
    .set_index("filter")[["date", "value"]]
    .to_dict(orient="index")
)

sum_buys = {k : {v["date"] : v["value"]} for k, v in sum_buys_data.items()}

sum_buys

{0.5: {20200512: 6.480628},
 0.6: {20200512: 7.463128},
 0.7: {20200512: 8.684414}}
```

Now, but what if you have a lot of columns or want a more generalised approach? You still need to iterate, but we can tweak the `defaultdict` class so that the factory is aware of the missing key and creates a nested dictionary in the same vein. As far as timings go, ~20k rows get converted to a nested dictionary in about 170ms on my machine and ~200k rows in about 780ms.

```
# extra imports
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
np.random.seed(0)

size = 100000 # let's create a slightly bigger data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "name" : np.random.choice(["sum_buys", "sum_sells"], size=size),
    "filter" : np.random.choice(range(10), size=size),
    "date" : np.random.choice(range(1000), size=size),
    "value" : np.random.random(size)
}).drop_duplicates(subset=["name", "filter", "date"])

df.shape # (19861, 4)

# define a custom dictionary
class NestedDict(defaultdict):
    
    def __init__(self, f):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.f = f
        
    def __missing__(self, key):
        ret = NestedDict(self.f)
        self[key] = ret
        return ret

nested_dict = NestedDict(NestedDict)

for index, value in df.set_index(["name", "filter", "date"]).itertuples():
    n, f, d = index # unpack index into keys
    nested_dict[n][f][d] = value

nested_dict["sum_buys"][0][0] # 0.396...
```